# Multiply TensorVariable with random matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, octave

I have a `theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable` named *H*. I want to create a random matrix with the same size as *H*, whereas the matrix should have 1 values with probability *p*.

Currently I have this:

```
x = numpy.random.rand(...) * p
x = ...
H = H * T.shared(x)
```

The questions now are:

- How do I get the size of the `TensorVariable` *H*?
- How do I modify `x` from a matrix with random values between `0` and `p` to be a matrix where every value is 1 if the previous value is smaller than `p`.

If it helps, the octave version of the wanted code looks like this:

```
x = rand(size(H,1),size(H,2)) < p;
H = H .* x;
```

Edit:

I found [these examples](https://theano.readthedocs.org/en/rel-0.6rc3/library/tensor/raw_random.html) and tried solving it using theano: It says binominal returns the number of successes, but I need a matrix filled with 0s and 1. It's also possible to create random_integers with low value 0 and high value 1, but I cannot give a probability.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What where the problems?

Comment: I added a explanation what I found.

Comment: in numpy it will be something like: `x = rand(H.shape); H[x>=p]=0`